# Is there mass phone call in Watch Dogs series?

Tags: watch-dogs, watch-dogs-2

I am wondering: is it possible to make a mass call or mass SMS (to call/sms everyone around) in any series of Watch Dogs franchise?

I know it is possible to make a phone call to specific NPC, but can it be accomplished more than one of them?

Comment: As far as I know, in the first Watch Dogs this is not possible.

Comment: @pinckerman, maybe you could point some other game where this could be possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in Watch Dogs 2 you can get a skill to mass call people in an area, though it does take a lot of research points.